# How to integrate mv command after find command?

Tags: files, find, mv

I am searching for files which name which contain `AAA` within their path using following command:

```
find path_A -name "*AAA*"
```

Given the output showed by the above command, I want to move those files into another path, say `path_B`. Instead of moving those file one by one, can I  optimize the command by moving those files right after the find command?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

With GNU [mv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv):

```
find path_A -name '*AAA*' -exec mv -t path_B {} +
```

That will use find's `-exec` option which replaces the `{}` with each find result in turn and runs the command you give it. As explained in `man find`:

```
   -exec command ;
          Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
          arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
          an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.
```

In this case, we are using the `+` version of `-exec` so that we run as few `mv` operations as possible:

```
   -exec command {} +
          This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
          the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
          each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invoca‐
          tions of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
          matched  files.   The command line is built in much the same way
          that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of  `{}'
          is  allowed  within the command.  The command is executed in the
          starting directory.
```

Comment: Don't forget the "\;" at the end of the exec!

Comment: @Charles Roth: it's `+` which dows the job, you can read my quote above or `man find` instead

Comment: Thanks for this! I was trying to use `-exec mv {} path_b +` and it was failing with permissions errors. TBH, I still don't understand why, but `-exec mv -t path_b {} +` works a treat!

Comment: @JeremyDavis When using `-exec ... {} +`, the `{}` has to be the last thing before the `+`.  This is why he uses `mv -t destdir {} +` and not `mv {} destdir +`.  One cold have used `-exec mv {} destdir ';'` instead, but that would have executed `mv` once for each file.

Comment: A small remark: the same works with GNU `cp` as well.

Answer (score 44):

You could do something like below as well.

```
find path_A -name "*AAA*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} path_B
```

Where,

1. `-0` If there are blank spaces or characters (including newlines) many commands will not work. This option take cares of file names with
   blank space.
2. `-I` Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input. Also, unquoted blanks do not
   terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline
   character.

**Testing**

I created two directories as `sourcedir` and `destdir`. Now, I created bunch of files inside `sourcedir` as `file1.bak`, `file2.bak` and `file3 with spaces.bak`

Now, I executed the command as,

```
find . -name "*.bak" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} /destdir/
```

Now, inside the `destdir`, when I do `ls`, I could see that the files have moved from `sourcedir` to `destdir`.

**References**

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/

Comment: Works nicely on macOS (where the `-t` arg is not available on `mv`

Answer (score 38):

For the benefit of OS X users coming across this question, the syntax in OS X is slightly different. Assuming you do not want to search recursively in subdirectories of `path_A`:

```
find path_A -maxdepth 1 -name "*AAA*" -exec mv {} path_B \;
```

If you want to search all files recursively in `path_A`:

```
find path_A -name "*AAA*" -exec mv {} path_B \;
```

Comment: This is not a OS X specific syntax, it's the same with any `find` I've used. Good points: `-maxdepth` (espeically if path_B is a subdirectory - avoids `mv` trying to move files already there!) and using \; (so {} doesn't have to be the last parameter and normal `mv` syntax can be used)

Comment: I think @mannykary might have been referring to macOS's `mv`, which doesn't have `-t`. To work around this, you could install coreutils with Homebrew and then use `gmv -t`, or there are other solutions using e.g. xargs.

Answer (score 9):

The `-exec` is the best way to do this. If, for whatever reason, this is not an option, you can also read the results in a loop:

```
find path_A -name "*AAA*" -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do mv "$file" path_B; done
```

That's the safe way, it can deal with file names that contain spaces, newlines or other strange characters. A simpler way, but one that **fails unless your file names consist only of simple alphanumeric characters**, is

```
mv $(find path_A -name "*AAA*") path_B
```

But use the while loop.

Comment: The simpler way can still fail if `your file names consist only of simple alphanumeric characters`, e.g. if reaching `ARG_MAX`

Comment: It works BUT it deletes the original folder by moving all the files it contains, even if the extension is not the one you are looking for...

Answer (score 7):

Using only [POSIX features of `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (and [also of `mv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html)):

```
find path_A -name '*AAA*' -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" path_B' find-sh {} +
```

Further reading:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
for f in `find path_A -name "*AAA*"`; do mv $f /destination/dir/; done
```

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943) and also [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)