# find + delete only the files that end with .index

Tags: linux, find, rm

We have a Kafka production machine on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

1. How can we remove all the files under `/var/kafka/kafka-logs` that end with `.index`?
2. How can we move all the files that end with `.index`  to another folder, `/var/tmp/INDEX_BACKUP`?

Example contents under `/var/kafka/kafka-logs`:

```
./hd3gd.ewhd.pri.processed-98/00000000000000000011.index
./hd3gd.ewhd.pri.processed-99/00000000000000000000.index
./hd3gd.ewhd.suspected_relations-0/00000000000000000000.index
./hd3gd.ewhd.suspected_relations-1/00000000000000000000.index
./hd3gd.ewhd.suspected_relations-2/00000000000000000000.index
./hd3gd.ewhd.suspected_relations-3/00000000000000000000.index
./hd3gd.ewhd.suspected_relations-4/00000000000000000000.index
./hd3gd.ewhd.suspected_relations-5/00000000000000000000.index
./frfwjnwe.fwefew.heartbeat-0/00000000000000000000.index
./frfwjnwe.fwefew.heartbeat-1/00000000000000000000.index
./frfwjnwe.fwefew.heartbeat-1/00000000000000017239.index
./frfwjnwe.fwefew.heartbeat-2/00000000000000000000.index
./frfwjnwe.fwefew.heartbeat-2/00000000000000017238.index
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- to remove all files ending with `.index` under `/var/kafka/kafka-logs`, using GNU `find` or compatible:

  ```
  find /var/kafka/kafka-logs -name \*.index -delete
  ```

  POSIXly:

  ```
  find /var/kafka/kafka-logs -name \*.index -exec rm -f {} +
  ```
- to move them to another folder, with GNU `mv`:

  ```
  find /var/kafka/kafka-logs -name \*.index -exec mv -t /var/tmp/INDEX_BACKUP {} +
  ```

  POSIXly:

  ```
  find /var/kafka/kafka-logs -name \*.index -exec sh -c '
    exec mv "$@" /var/tmp/INDEX_BACKUP/' sh {} +
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Ad.1.:

```
find /var/kafka/kafka-logs -type f -name "*.index" -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Answer for the second question you can find here: [How to integrate mv command after find command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154818/how-to-integrate-mv-command-after-find-command).

Answer (score 0):

Such command will work faster (comparing with find / -exec) due to larger arguments to rm command at once. This not requires GNU find.

Q1.

```
find /var/kafka/kafka-logs -type f -name "*.index" | xargs rm
```

Q2.

```
find /var/kafka/kafka-logs -name "*.index" | xargs -I {} mv {} /var/tmp/INDEX_BACKUP
```

Also note, that GNU find does not support ACLs or Extended Attributes, so you definitely do not want to use GNU find on Solaris.

Comment: It will not work faster that @StephenKitt's `-delete` where the deletion is done internally by `find` and would be a lot faster than invoking a separate `rm` utility in a child process. It's not faster than `-exec rm -f {} +` either which like `xargs` runs as few `rm` invocations as necessary. But it has a few problems like: it breaks with file names containing blanks, newlines, quotes..., If `rm` issues a prompt, it will read the response from the output of `find`.

Comment: Dear @Stéphane, not all systems have GNU find. For example Solaris 10.

Comment: `-exec rm -f {} +` is standard, added to SysV in the mid 80s. In POSIX since 1992. Actually, GNU find was one of the last ones to support it. Solaris definitely supports it. `-delete` is a GNU extension (though also supported by a few other implementations now).

Comment: Solaris11 supports `-delete` only in its GNU extension (/usr/gnu/bin/find). Solaris10 has not it preinstalled, admin needs install it.

Comment: And please note that GNU find does not support ACLs or Extended Attributes, so you definitely do not want to use GNU find on Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash` and assuming that there are not *thousands* of these files:

1. `rm /var/kafka/kafka-logs/**.index`
2. `mv /var/kafka/kafka-logs/**.index /var/tmp/INDEX_BACKUP`

   This would not check whether the names on the destination already exist, so it may overwrite files there (with your example files, you would only end up with a single copy of the `00000000000000000000.index` file, for example).

Both of these commands assumes that the `globstar` shell option has been set in `bash` using

```
shopt -s globstar
```

This enables the `**` glob pattern, which will match like `*` but across `/` in pathnames.