# Recursively rename all the files without changing their extensions?

Tags: files, find, rename, mv, recursive

How to recursively rename all the files in several layers of subdirectories without changing their extensions?

Below's a toned down version (to save room) of what I've got. 
For argument's sake, I want all the files to have the same title, yet retain their original extension. There's never more than a single file per directory, so there's no chance of doubling up.

For simplicity, we'll just call them all `foo`, followed by their current extension.

So just to clarify:
`Asset\ 1.pdf`, `Asset\ 1.png`, `Asset\ 1@4x.png`, `Asset\ 1.svg`
Will become:
`foo.pdf`, `foo.png`, `foo.png`, `foo.svg`
And so on in that fashion.

---

I would typically use parameter expansion and a `for` loop, like:

```
for f in */*; do mv "$f" "${f%/*}/foo.${f##*.}"; done
```

But it's not recursive. So I would prefer to use something with `find`..`-exec` or similar.

---

```
~/Desktop/Project/Graphics/
├── Huge
│   ├── PDF
│   │   └── Asset\ 1.pdf
│   ├── PNG
│   │   ├── 1x
│   │   │   └── Asset\ 1.png
│   │   └── 4x
│   │       └── Asset\ 1@4x.png
│   └── SVG
│       └── Asset\ 1.svg
├── Large
│   ├── PDF
│   │   └── ProjectAsset\ 2.pdf
│   ├── PNG
│   │   ├── 1x
│   │   │   └── ProjectAsset\ 2.png
│   │   └── 4x
│   │       └── ProjectAsset\ 2@4x.png
│   └── SVG
│       └── ProjectAsset\ 2.svg
├── Medium
│   ├── PDF
│   │   └── ProjectAsset\ 3.pdf
│   ├── PNG
│   │   ├── 1x
│   │   │   └── ProjectAsset\ 3.png
│   │   └── 4x
│   │       └── ProjectAsset\ 3@4x.png
│   └── SVG
│       └── ProjectAsset\ 3.svg
├── Small
│   ├── PDF
│   │   └── ProjectAsset\ 4.pdf
│   ├── PNG
│   │   ├── 1x
│   │   │   └── ProjectAsset\ 4.png
│   │   └── 4x
│   │       └── ProjectAsset\ 4@4x.png
│   └── SVG
│       └── ProjectAsset\ 4.svg
└── Tiny
    ├── PDF
    │   └── Asset\ 5.pdf
    ├── PNG
    │   ├── 1x
    │   │   └── Asset\ 5.png
    │   └── 4x
    │       └── Asset\ 5@4x.png
    └── SVG
        └── Asset\ 5.svg

30 directories, 20 files
```

Comment: You can use a combination of `find` and GNU `mv` like described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154819/316810).

Comment: @feliks This system has mostly BSD utilities. But I think it is basically the same.

Comment: @feliks useful link, but the challenge lies in getting `find x -exec y {} \;` to play nicely with `"${parameter%/*}/foo.${expansion##*.}"`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It's very similar with `find...-exec`: invoke a shell so that you can use parameter expansion, extract the `PARENT` directory and the `EXTENSION` so that you can construct the new filename as `PARENT/NAME.EXTENSION` and then move/rename:

```
find target_dir -name '?*.*' -type f -exec sh -c '
  ret=0
  for file do
    head=${file%/*}
    mv -- "$file" "$head/NAME.${file##*.}" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"' sh {} +
```

If you want to dry-run the above, insert an `echo` before the `mv`...

Beware it also processes hidden files.

---

If you have access to `zsh` you could run:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(*.*)' '${1}NAME.${2:e}'
```

remove the `-n` if you're happy with the result.

Hidden files are skipped by default, but you can use the `(#qD)` glob qualifier if you want them processed:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(?*.*)(#qD)' '${1}NAME.${2:e}'
```

Comment: What's the second `sh` for?

Comment: This `-exec {} \;` calls a new shell per each file found

Comment: @tjt263 The "second sh" is not a command, it is the name of the shell started by `sh -c`, change it to `findsh` if you wish.

Comment: Can it be omitted?

Comment: @tjt263 - why ? Yes, you can but then you have to change `$1`s to `$0`s... See [What does the x in "find ... -exec sh -c '...' x {}" mean?](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/find/#shell)

Comment: @don_crissti Well, my question to you is, why bother/what's the point? It makes a complicated command line slightly more complicated, with no benefit that I can see. I'm happy to be corrected though.

Comment: @tjt263 - the benefit is explained in the link in my comment. I don't have anything to add, really... Feel free to not use it but then, as I said, you'll have to adjust the parameters accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

If using bash, your idea could walk all directories:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ for f in ./Desktop/**/*; do [[ -f $f ]] && 
           mv -n "$f" "${f%/*}/foo.${f##*.}"; done
```

Added `-n` to `mv` to avoid overwriting existing files (if any).

That could also be done with find (in **one** call to the shell (faster than one shell per file)):

```
$ find ./Desktop -type f -exec sh -c '
       for f; do echo mv -n "$f" "${f%/*}/foo.${f##*.}"; done' findsh {} \+
```

Remove the `echo` if the command does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but, if you know the max depth of the directory hierarchy (here: 3), why not

```
for f in */* */*/* */*/*/*; do ... ; done
```

adding some error checking?

Comment: Did you give it a try? Worked for me, going through all the subdirectory levels.

Answer (score 0):

Finding all regular files in or below the directory `~/Desktop/Project/Graphics` whose names start with `Asset 1` and replacing that part of the name with the string `foo`:

```
find ~/Desktop/Project/Graphics -type f -name 'Asset 1*' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        dir=${pathname%/*}
        name=${pathname##*/Asset 1}
        mv -i "$pathname" "$dir/foo$name"
    done' sh {} +
```

In the above, `$name` will be the part of the original filename with `Asset 1` removed from the start.

To replace the whole filename but keep the filename suffix (and also matching any file starting with `Asset` (with space after the word)):

```
find ~/Desktop/Project/Graphics -type f -name 'Asset *' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        dir=${pathname%/*}
        name=${pathname##*.}
        mv -i "$pathname" "$dir/foo$name"
    done' sh {} +
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score 0):

```
find ~/Desktop/Project/Graphics/ -type f -exec sh -c 'f={}; mv $f ${f%/*}/foo.${f##*.}' \;
```

`sh` means invoking default shell. you can change it to bash, zsh and so on.