# How to move all the files with specific prefix of the directory?

Tags: find, regular-expression, quoting, mv

I have a following directory structure (assume no two files have the same name):

- Apple1

  - apple1.jpg
  - apple2.jpg
- Apple2

  - apple3.jpg
  - apple4.jpg
- Apple3
- Tomato
- Peach

And i would like to move one directory to the top directory all the `*.jpg` files inside the directories, which names start from `Apple`.

As a result I expect the Apple directories to be empty and the images from Apple directories to be in the top.

I have tried doing like `mv "Apple*/*.jpg" .`, or `find . "Apple*/*.jpg" -exec mv -t . {} +`  as prescribed here [How to integrate mv command after find command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154818/how-to-integrate-mv-command-after-find-command). But this doesn't work.

When executing `mv` i receive a following message:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘Apple*/*.jpg’: No such file or directory
```

Seems like it has not found anything matching the pattern. And other option simply outputs nothing. Maybe the reason is, that in the case of subdirectories regular expression needs to be modified?

I would be very grateful for help and suggestions.

Comment: A picture is worth ~ 1k words, so post a tree diagram of what you want the post-move dir structure to look like.

Comment: @guest_7 I would like to simply move all the images to the root directory as I've mentioned

Comment: What is the error you get when you run the move command `mv Apple*/*.jpg .`?

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work? What you currently doesn't show enough regarding what you want to do.

Comment: @NasirRiley I would like to move all the files, which end on `*.jpg` from directories, which start on `Apple` to the topl level of the hierarchy. My current solution is most probably a nonsense - and I am asking how to achieve the needed fuctionality.

Comment: More information is needed. What exactly isn't working? Are there are any error messages? If so, what commands are causing them? Add this to your question and not in the comments.

Comment: You need to remove those quotes from the move command for the globbing to happen.

Comment: @guest_7 wow, the resolution was so simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Quasímodo in my particular case - this situation is not the case. However, in general, it is really worth considering this situation